# Is there a way to not give a point if they get it wrong the first time, quiz, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and am doing a basic quiz. I'm running into a problem for scoring.

```
trials = 3
for i in range(trials):
    ans_2 = ansTwo()
    results.append(ans_2)
    if ans_2 in ('c','C'):
        print("Good Job",name)
        score+=1
        break
    else:
        remaining = trials-i-1
        s = '' if remaining == 1 else 's'
        print("Oops Try Again? [{0} Chance{1} Remaining]".format(remaining, s))
```

This is my code and I'm trying to make it that if they do not get the answer the first time they do not get any points, but if they get the answer the first time they get a point.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if statement before `score += 1` that checks if the loop is running for the first time. In your case:

```
if i == 0:
    score += 1
```